# The best way to do a MYSQL STRAIGHT_JOIN in the query builder of CodeIgniter [old version 2]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, inner-join, codeigniter-2

A project uses an older version of the CodeIgniter[2.1.1].
The query builder is used to retrieve specific data.
The source code is an example like this:

```
$db
  ->from('first as A')
  ->where_in('A.code', $first_values)
  ->join('second as B', 'A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active', 'inner')
  ->where_in('B.code', $second_values)
  ->join('third as C', 'A.key_id = C.key_id and A.key2_id = C.key2_id and C.active', 'inner')
  ->where_in('C.code', $third_values)
  ->select('COUNT(A.key_id) AS cnt')
  ->order_by('A.key_id', 'desc')
  ->order_by('A.key2_id', 'desc')
  ->order_by('A.key3_id', 'desc')
;
```

This will generate the following SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.key_id) as cnt
FROM first AS A
INNER JOIN second AS B ON A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active
INNER JOIN third AS C ON A.key_id = C.key_id and A.key2_id = C.key2_id and C.active
WHERE A.code IN ('someone')
AND B.code IN ('1','2','3')
AND C.code IN ('4','5','6')
ORDER BY A.key_id desc, A.key2_id desc, A.key3_id desc
```

From here on, the problem is.
The order of the tables to be joined depends on the environment in which this SQL is executed.
And the problem is that the index is no longer used because of the join order.
Perhaps the environment is such that one table is extremely large and the optimizer makes different decisions.
In the range I tried, I think that there is no choice but to specify the join order with STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Therefore, I searched for a way to realize STRAIGHT_JOIN with the query builder of CodeIgniter[2.1.1].

The first thing I thought about was writing in the SELECT part.

```
  ->select('STRAIGHT_JOIN COUNT(A.key_id) AS cnt')
```

I think it's good because the order is still specified and the index is used.
However, although omitted in the example, when joining multiple tables, it seems that the overall order is specified, so it is unclear whether it is optimal or not.

The next idea was to be able to execute a function on a table-by-table basis.
Below is where the file was added.

```
├── application
│   ├── core
│   │   └── MY_Loader.php       // require 'application/database/DB.php'
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── DB_active_rec.php   // added straight_join function
│   │   └── DB.php              // require 'application/database/DB_active_rec.php'
```

I think it's okay to add it to the join function, but I created a dedicated function.

```
public function straight_join($table, $cond)
{
    $this->_track_aliases($table);
    if (preg_match('/([\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/', $cond, $match))
    {
        $match[1] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[1]);
        $match[3] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[3]);

        $cond = $match[1].$match[2].$match[3];
    }
    $join = 'STRAIGHT_JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE).' ON '.$cond;
    $this->ar_join[] = $join;
    if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
    {
        $this->ar_cache_join[] = $join;
        $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'join';
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Then change the join of a table to STRAIGHT_JOIN.

```
  ->straight_join('second as B', 'A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active')
```

---

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter.
At the moment, I think the only way to get the data is to join with STRAIGHT_JOIN.
If the extension method is wrong, or if you have already tried STRAIGHT_JOIN in CodeIgniter, please give me an example or the best way.

---

This post focuses on how to implement the CodeIgniter, so this is a bit different from the main point in this case, but I'll write it here for reference.

```
SELECT
    A.key_id
FROM
    first as A
INNER JOIN
    second as B ON A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active
INNER JOIN
    third as C ON A.key_id = C.key_id and A.key2_id = C.key2_id and C.active
WHERE
    A.code IN ('someone')
```

In this case, the join order is A, B, C.
A`[type:ref,ref:const]`, B`[type:eq_ref,ref:A.key_id]`, C`[type:eq_ref,ref:A.key2_id]`

```
SELECT
    A.key_id
FROM
    first as A
INNER JOIN
    second as B ON A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active
INNER JOIN
    third as C ON A.key_id = C.key_id and A.key2_id = C.key2_id and C.active
WHERE
    A.code IN ('someone')
AND
    B.code IN ('1','2','3')
```

However, adding the WHERE clause changes the order, and it seems that the index is not used and it is a full scan.
In this case, the join order is B, C, A.
B`[type:ALL,ref:NULL]`, C`[type:ref,ref:B.key_id]`, A`[type:ref,ref:C.key2_id]`
(You can get the same result by using left join instead of inner join.)

For databases in a development environment with the same configuration, the join order is expected[A,B,C]. (Although the number of registered data is small and different.)

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in first join simply - LEFT is always STRAIGHT_JOIN, and it will be converted to INNER back due to WHERE condition.

Comment: Thank you. When changed to LEFT `LEFT JOIN second AS B ON A.key_id = B.key_id and B.active LEFT JOIN third AS C ON A.key_id = C.key_id and A.key2_id = C.key2_id and C.active`, the join order will not be as expected, EXPLAIN's "type" will be "ALL" and "Extra" will be "Using Temporary", and the index will not be applied.

Comment: I don't know why so... try to renew tables statistic, try to force index usage... One more option - rewrite your query from INNER JOIN to WHERE EXISTS, in this case the tables scanning order should be fixed too (and maybe the query will be improved even).

Comment: PS. Your query contains implicit GROUP BY and returns one row only. What is the reason in ORDER BY for it? one row sorting is strange...

Comment: I'm sorry, the above is just an example to shorten it, and you actually get multiple values. Even if it is simplified as above, it will not be in the expected order. However, it depends on the database environment. It doesn't go as expected in an environment with a huge amount of certain data.

Comment: *It doesn't go as expected in an environment with a huge amount of certain data.* ??? the logical correctnes of the query does not depend of the rows amount.

Comment: Yes. However, even after trying various queries (which are actually more complicated), the join order doesn't come out as expected, so I think about that use a STRAIGHT_JOIN that can get the expected value, given the time and cost of the project.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can analyze it from the MySQL side.  There may be a simple index change to make it work faster.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't write in a detailed table definition. I'm not sure if that helps, but I've added some symptoms. Because of this, I don't have much time, so I'm thinking of solving the problem with STRAIGHT_JOIN. I don't have the authority, but I'll talk about updating statistics, rebuilding indexes, etc. within the project.